# Push a UIViewController onto UINavigationController from a UIView?

Tags: iphone

Typically, my event handling occurs in the UIViewController, so i used the following line of code:
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];`

However, now my event handler is in the UIView.
specifically, i'm using `- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`

So from inside my touchesEnded delegate, how do i push a UIViewController onto a 
UINavigationController from a UIView that is a subview of the UIViewController mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a delegate on your view so that you can refer back to the view's viewController. This could be done like this:

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView
{ 
    id delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

Then in your View controller, you will simply set the view's delegate like this:

```
[myCustomView setDelegate:self];
```

Which will allow you to send messages to your delegate from within your custom view

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [delegate customMessage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to your `UIViewController` to your `UIView`. Then in the event handler, send a message to the `UIViewController` that will push the other controller. You could also do the push in the event handler, but the other way is more 'correct' in a MVC architecture.